# save a multidimensional array to txt

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Hi I have an array that stores products. Here is an example of the first product:

```
$_SESSION['pricebook']['product1'] = array(
'name' => 'product1',
'description'=>'Board my Cat(s)!',
'price'=>25.95,
);
```

And I have an array for the cart that stores each product a user selects from the pricebook array.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
$_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}
```

How would I write the cart into an orders.txt file? Everything I have tried has given me the  "Array Notice: Array to string conversion" error.

Note: the product is added to the cart as so:

```
if (isset($_GET["product1"]) && $_GET["product1"]=="Add") {
$pid = $_GET["name"];   
if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'][ $pid ])) { $_SESSION['cart'][ $pid ]; }
array_push($_SESSION['cart'][ $pid ]);
}
```

Also is there any way that it can be saved to a txt file in a human readable format kinda like a receipt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PHP's [`serialize()`](http://php.net/serialize) for this.

> Generates a storable representation of a value.
>
> This is useful for storing or passing PHP values around without losing their type and structure.
>
> To make the serialized string into a PHP value again, use [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).

To save, your code could look like this

```
$representation = serialize($_SESSION['cart']);
// save $representation to your txt file/whatever
```

and to load the values, just do as is said in the manual

```
// load data into $representation 
$_SESSION['cart'] = unserialize($representation);
```

---

If you want a prettier format, you can use [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/json_encode) with the `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` flag set

```
$representation = json_encode($_SESSION['cart'], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
// save $representation to your txt file/whatever

// load data into $representation 
$_SESSION['cart'] = json_decode($representation);
```

Comment: Is it possible to store it so that it is human readable like a receipt?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$handle = fopen('orders.txt', 'w+'); // change this based on how you would like to update the file
fwrite($handle, print_r($_SESSION['cart']), true);
fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use either `serialize` or `json_encode`.

You could use serialize() like this

```
$t = serialize($_SESSION['cart']);
file_put_contents('filename.txt', $t);
```

Or json_encode()

```
$t = json_encode($_SESSION['cart']);
file_put_contents('filename.txt', $t);
```

`serialize` will work a tiny little bit faster, but is PHP specific, while `json_encode` will produce a JSON string that can be fed into anything, including a toaster :D The JSON string also leaves a smaller footprint than the serialized one.